# htaccess pretty URL with PHP & URL variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hoping someone can offer some assistance here. This is an issue with multiple layers. In short, I want to have pretty URLs that use a URL variable to a file within a folder.

So, I want http://www.example.com/?page=path/to/page to look like http://www.example.com/path/to/page/

On the index.php page, to load the above content:

```
require_once('content/'.$_GET['page'].'.php');
```

Current htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Add trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Make URLs sexy!
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I can get this to work with a top level page within the /content folder, however, when the php file I with to include is within a folder inside the /content folder, it does not work.

Any ideas?? I believe the issue comes down to using an addition / in the ?page= variable. htaccess doesnt seem to like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing, I figured it out. My regex was off.

Changed:

```
# Make URLs sexy!
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```